# Run external code or application on connected client desktop from application that published via RemoteApp or Citrix ICA?

Tags: c#, windows, remote-desktop, citrix, remoteapp

I have desktop app on server, that can be used by clients via Microsoft RDP or RemoteApp or Citrix ICA. And now i need to somehow interact with REAL user desktop from that application running on server in RDP/RemoteApp/ICA session.

Is there exists some server-side API in Microsoft RDP/RemoteApp or Citrix ICA that can be used to implement this?

My app is currently written in C#, but i can easily use  COM/WinAPI if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, on Citrix you can use the Virtual Channel SDK:

https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/sdks/virtual-channel-sdk.html

Microsoft also has something similar if you want to use RDP:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you! Tried examples - it's working nice. Requirement of plugin's installation is sad, but possible in by my situation - at least they don't require administrator privileges to do so. :)